# Prisma Migration Status Unclear

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I am using prisma to manage a postgres database, and encountering what seems like an inconsistency in the migration state.

When I run `npx prisma migrate status`, I get:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "mydb", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"

1 migration found in prisma/migrations


Database schema is up to date!
```

So far so good.

But when I run `npx prisma migrate dev` directly after that (expecting no changes to show up), I get this output:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "mydb", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"


⚠️  Warnings for the current datasource:

  • A unique constraint covering the columns `[column name]` on the table `[table name]` will be added. If there are existing duplicate values, this will fail.

✔ Are you sure you want create and apply this migration?
```

The problem is that this particular column keeps getting added and dropped in every migration, even though it has not been touched in the schema (and even prisma recognizes it has not been).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11631), resolved in a later version of prisma.